# date_default_timezone_set("Europe/London") does not return correct time

Tags: php, timezone, default-value, date-format

When I use following code to get current London time, it gives the wrong time.

At the time of testing the current London time was **02:11:16 PM, Wednesday 01, June 2011**, but I using the following code:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
echo date('m/d/y h:i a', time());
```

Gave me: **06/02/11 02:12 am**

Why did it not return correct London time?

Comment: Can you show some real life code and what it outputs? Also which time zone you are in? What does the function call return, `true` or `false`?

Comment: Is the time on the server correct? I mean, server itself, not PHP.

Comment: Server time wrong.

Answer (score 16):

```
date_default_timezone_set("Europe/London");
```

try with double quotes. works on godaddy

Comment: The quotes make no difference here, in this case the single quotes are more correct since there are no interpolated vars or special characters.

Answer (score 1):

Check your ini file whether timezone is set or not,

```
ini_set('date.timezone', 'Europe/London');
```

Try this it should work.

Comment: thnx 4 reply but now it shows 12hrs forward from uk/london time